# Something is failing when trying to re-activate a button with ng-disable

Tags: angularjs

I've got this HTML:

```
 <form ng-controller="controlFormulario as formCtrl">
  <div style="width:50%; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 2%">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputTitulo">Título</label>
      <input type="titulo" class="form-control" id="inputTitulo" ng-model="formData.titulo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputTexto">Texto</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="inputTexto" ng-model="formData.texto"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
      <input type="fecha" class="form-control" id="fecha" ng-model="formData.fecha" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
      <button  class="btn btn-primary" style="height:35px;width:100px;float:right;"  id="submit"
      ng-disabled="isDisabled()">
      Enviar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Which works with this controller:

var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('controlFormulario', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.formData = { // Reservamos una variable que contendrá el texto del input.
    "author":"",
    "text":"",
    "fecha": new Date()
  };

$scope.isDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.formData.text == "" || $scope.formData.author == "";
}

}]);
```

Most data bindings are working properly, but there is a problem with that button: it won't ever activate. I tried many things and been struggling with this problem since yesterday, and I could write a lot of text about how many things I tried and how none of them actually worked. This is my third thread regarding this problem, so maybe you can understand why I am so frustrated with this silly thing.

The idea is simple: if I write something on the author and text fields, the button should get active. Pretty straightforward! But, why doesn't it work, then? Any idea?

edit: I also trying not using the $scope and going for the controller functionality, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v821npgw/

Your are mixing scope and controllerAs, try to use one.

I have change to use controllerAs and why your button never get activate is because of your disabled function is checking:

```
$scope.formData.text == "" || $scope.formData.author == "";
```

formData.author is always true because your author is empty.

To have the button enable you need to have text in author and text input field.